# Why the class Cougar needs to implement a public version of the method at line 5 when it does not have a method at this line( about overload)

Tags: java, overloading

I understand that "the method getTailLength() in the interface Hastail is assumed to be public, since it is part of an interface, therefore, the implementation of the method on line 3  `protected int getTailLength() {return 4;}` is an invalid override".

But I don't know why line 5 is incorrect. The explanation says that"the class Cougar implement an overloaded version of getTailLength(),but since the declaration in the parent class Puma is invalid, it needs to implement a public version of the method".

This line does not contain the `getTailLength()` method,why it needs to implement a public version of the method?

Sorry for the stupid question, I am trying my best to understand it.

```
interface HasTail { int getTailLength(); }
abstract class Puma implements HasTail {
 protected int getTailLength() {return 4;}
}
public class Cougar extends Puma {
 public static void main (String[] args) {
 Puma puma = new Puma();
 System.out.println(puma.getTailLength());
}
public int getTailLength(int Length); {return 2;}  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you can't change the method signature from `public` to `protected` **and** *still* implement the `public` interface from `HasTail`. In Java 8+, it is also possible to provide a `default` method body to the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Your code formatting is not good, and because of this, you're missing a mistake: This semicolon is messing you up:

```
public int getTailLength(int Length); {return 2;}
```

In *correctly* formatted Java, this is equivalent to:

```
public int getTailLength(int Length) {
     // empty method
}; 


{
    return 2;
}
```

Code formatting *matters*, don't be sloppy, for your sake and for ours.